# InetAddress#getLoopbackAddress trustworthiness against DNS spoofing

Tags: java, security, dns, localhost

Some static code analysis tools complain when InetAddress#getLoopbackAddress is used to obtain the loop back address as it is said to be vulnerable to DNS spoofing.

Does the result InetAddress#getLoopbackAddress need to go through DNS-resolution before being used?

What would be an acceptable alternative to go around this?

Comment: Hard to see how. It's 127.0.0.1, or the IPv6 equivalent.